Reduce an Image in C
Hello fellow programmers. I'm new to the forum so please bear with me.
What I am trying to achieve is taking a loaded image from file(e.g. background wallpaper image 4000x2250) and scale it down to native resolution of 1360x768. In the same fashion as a modern OS when you set a wallpaper image for your desktop.
typedef struct {
    UINT8 Blue;
    UINT8 Green;
    UINT8 Red;
    UINT8 Reserved;
} EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_BLT_PIXEL;

typedef EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_BLT_PIXEL   GUI_PIXEL;

typedef struct {
    UINT32    Width;
    UINT32    Height;
    BOOLEAN   HasAlpha;
    GUI_PIXEL *PixelData;
} GUI_IMAGE;

GUI_IMAGE* ReduceImage(GUI_IMAGE* image)
{
    UINT32 resizeWidth = image->Width / 2;
    UINT32 resizeHeight = image->Height / 2;
    UINT32 x;
    UINT32 y;
    UINT32 row = 0;
    UINT32 column = 0;
    GUI_IMAGE *NewImage;

    NewImage = AllocateZeroPool(sizeof(GUI_IMAGE));
    if (NewImage == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    NewImage->PixelData = AllocateZeroPool(resizeWidth * resizeHeight *
sizeof(GUI_PIXEL));
    if (NewImage->PixelData == NULL) 
    {
        FreePool(NewImage);
        return NULL;
    }

    NewImage->Width = resizeWidth;
    NewImage->Height = resizeHeight;
    NewImage->HasAlpha = TRUE;

    for(y = 0; y < resizeHeight - 1; y++)
    {
        for(x = 0; x < resizeWidth - 1; x++)
        {
            NewImage->PixelData[(resizeWidth) * y + x] = image->PixelData[(image->Width) * row + column];
            column += 2;
        }
        row += 2;
        column = 0;
    }

    return NewImage;
}


"a cut off image is displayed to the screen" --> does this happen when the target size image is the same as the original?

void ReduceImage( ..., GUI_IMAGE* result,... Big Red Flag... There is no way the caller has access to the buffer allocated in this function... Probably need a double pointer, but there's not enough code presented to know for sure what's happening...

@ chux - Reinstate Monica - the code is written to only run if the source image width/height is larger than the target width height...

@ Fe2O3 - GUI_IMAGE* result is actually a global in my C file if that helps.

How you call ReduceImage() is really important (and not shown?)  because of parameters targetWidth and targetHeight  . . . they really need to be smaller than original image width and image height, respectively.  They also need to be in bounds.  I know this is elementary, and chances are good you cared for it, but . . . it would be my 1st check, in the spirit of moving from simple to complex debugging method.

@ greg spears - My call is ReduceImage(LoadedImageFromFile(e.g. *.jpeg, *.png, *.bmp), GlobalImage, NativeWidth, NativeHeight); All loaded images are larger than the native screen res purposefully. I have changed some of the code which eliminated the hang but the end result is hex value's with no header and no end which make the image undisplayable.

@Mike "GUI_IMAGE* result is actually a global" That makes no difference. The parameter variable of the same name shadows the global variable. (Print out both addresses (%p) to see the difference.) The local (parameter) variable is used within the function body, having NO effect on the "global" variable's value... Quick fix: remove that parameter from the function's collection and use the "global" variable only... Not good, but that will patch this code for the time being...

@Fe2O3 - Made changes to the code as per your suggestion however I stall have the same outcome... The image is a garbled render the width of the screen by .5 inch of pixel area.

@MikeAmbrose No one can help you with code they cannot see. The (imo) glaring problem I pointed out with this single function suggests that the entire code may be riddled with bugs. You don't take your spare tire to the mechanic and ask why the engine doesn't start. This is no different.

@MikeAmbrose Read and think about this recent Q&A. Posit: Your original image is 1000x1000 and you want it to be 100x100. As written, this code will perform 10^6 loops to get 10^4 pixels. Not great. Imagine driving the loops to populate each destination pixel by calculating which source pixel is used... Even though they'd be quick, eliminating 99% of the loops (in this example) would be worthwhile, no?

@Fe2O3 - I rewrote the entire function from scratch and it works perfectly by reducing the image by half.. My next question is how could I possibly optimize the code for speed and how might I write it to reduce an image to screen resolution?

@MikeAmbrose Code looks better (although not seeing everything.) How to scale? Lay two rulers side by side, where one is "cm" and the other "inches"... Study where the "whole number" values line up, and think about how you'd scale to get 12 inches from the 30cm. Both the x and y axis of the src and dst rectangle will have their own "scaling factor"... This is basic math from school days. To get the dst pixel for 1", use the src pixel at 2.56cm. Because there are only pixels as 2 and 3, you'd round up and grab src pixel #3. Wash, rinse, repeat... Optimising is not a concern until it all works.

Thank you for all the help! I figured it out.
// macro to return -/+ half value
#define RoundValue(x)  ((x)>=0?(long)((x)+0.5):(long)((x)-0.5))

GUI_IMAGE* ScaleImage(GUI_IMAGE* image)
{
    float ratio; // >1 is enlarging(e.g. 1.1), <1 is reducing(e.g. 0.4)
    UINT32 resWidth;
    UINT32 resHeight;
    UINT32 x;
    UINT32 y;
    UINT32 x_in;
    UINT32 y_in;
    GUI_IMAGE *NewImage;

    // get screen resolution for x and y
    GetResolution(&resWidth, &resHeight);

    // calculate ratio
    ratio = (float)resWidth / (float)image->Width;

    // allocate space for the new image
    NewImage = AllocateZeroPool(sizeof(GUI_IMAGE));
    if (NewImage == NULL)
    {
        // if no allocation, return NULL
        return NULL;
    }

    // allocate space for pixel data
    NewImage->PixelData = AllocateZeroPool(resWidth * resHeight * sizeof(GUI_PIXEL));
    if (NewImage->PixelData == NULL) 
    {
        // if no allocation, return NULL
        FreePool(NewImage);
        return NULL;
    }

    // set image attributes
    NewImage->Width = resWidth;
    NewImage->Height = resHeight;
    NewImage->HasAlpha = TRUE;

    // loop through x and y coordinates of the entire screen
    for(y = 0; y < resHeight; y++)
    {
        for(x = 0; x < resWidth; x++)
        {
            // calculate target area and set new pixel data from original data
            x_in = RoundValue((float)x / ratio);
            y_in = RoundValue((float)y / ratio);
            NewImage->PixelData[resWidth * y + x] = image->PixelData[image->Width * y_in + x_in];
        }
    }

    // return new image
    return NewImage;
}


Congrats... However, there's this that the code is not handling quite right. You get to decide if you want to have black borders left/right or top/bottom OR if the image should be stretched/squished so shifting between two different "aspect ratios" still fills the display area of the destination. (Or, even "cropping" one or two edges that might be too wide/high.) Have fun!

@Fe2O3 - Might you be able to show me how one could implement, say a 16:9 aspect ratio into the code above?

If the original and the target are both 16:9, there's no problem. Analog photos come in a range of dimensions; 3x5, 4x6, 8x10,... Each is a different aspect ratio. Play with any image edit software (even Windows Paint)... I cannot teach you everything in an exchange of comments here. Start reading, making notes, exploring and thinking. Search here on SO for "Sobel filter". That's not scaling, but is image manipulation. Good luck!

@Fe2O3 - Thanks for the direction, feedback, idea's, etc... However some code for analysis or usage would have been great. As the topic states I am working with relatively large images such as pc desktop wallpaper and not standard size pictures and photographs. The code is intact and working at this point and could be easily expanded upon at will.

The code is not too bad, but... Dealing with floating point is both slower that integer calculations, AND it risks UB... 12 * 2.56 = 30.72... If the code is expecting to find the "maximum" corresponding pixel at 31, the code will be accessing outside of the boundaries of the array... Suggest you post a new question here, or on the "Code Review" site for more information. Good for you that you rewrote and got something much better than you'd started with! Keep going!!

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
